# How do I pass data from activity to fragment in android

Tags: java, android

I found this but It doesn't work, please help! (this is just a test app I created to test this, I assure you I am actually using this for a real app in the play store)

```
//Activity
Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putString("param1", "test p1");
        b.putString("param2", "test p2");
        BlankFragment c = new BlankFragment();
        c.setArguments(b);

//Frag

private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
    }
```

Comment: What doesn't work and how do you start your fragment?

Answer (score 0):

In Activity

```
Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putString("param1", "test p1");
        b.putString("param2", "test p2");
        BlankFragment c = new BlankFragment();
        c.setArguments(b);
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        final FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.add(<ID_OF_FRAG_IN_XML>, c).commit();
```